# Prevent ESModules from being deferred when imported with script tag

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I've setup differential loading to serve ES6 modules to newer browsers. I've run into a problem where modules are deferred by default with the script tag even without the defer attribute. I.e.

```html
<script type="module" src="..."></script>
```

is always deferred till all the HTML is parsed leading to a FOUC.

I've tried to prevent this and force parsing the file before the rest of the HTML is loaded by using

```html
<script defer="false" type="module" src="..."></script>

<script defer="nodefer" type="module" src="..."></script>

<script async="false" type="module" src="..."></script>
```

None of these approaches seem to work. Whatever technique I use has to maintain differentiation between the ES6 and ES5 bundles. How do I prevent ESModules from being deferred till all the HTML is parsed even when included in the head?

Answer (score 5):

As seen [here](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/), you can't disable defer on module scripts:

> Module scripts behave like defer by default – there's no way to make a module script block the HTML parser while it fetches.

However, to load ES6 modules in browser that support it and have ES5 modules available for backup, you can use `nomodule` as [described here](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-es-modules/):

> Older browsers won’t execute scripts with an unknown “type”, but you can define fallback scripts with the `nomodule` attribute:
>
> ```
> <script type="module" src="module.js"></script>
> <script nomodule src="fallback.js"></script>
> ```

If you're just worried about FOUC, hide your content until you're ready or ensure necessary CSS is inlined in the `head`.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a way to use differential loading and non-deferred scripts together. I can't directly inline styles because I need hot module replacement to work. HMR works by including a script that injects styles as I edit them in the IDE. In production, the FUOC is not an issue as I extract the styles but my website is partially server-rendered and partially react. I need above the fold React to load before the rest of the html is parsed. It's not user friendly when the bottom half of the page shows up before the top of half of the page, (which is in React)

Comment: @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth Load your server-rendered content as hidden initially then have React unhide it when it's ready.

Comment: Except that's less efficient than my previous set up of including a normal script that halts parsing below the fold till the top half is ready. I ran into your links on my search to setup differential loading, I posted this is to see if there is any updated official resource confirming that ESModules cannot block HTML Parsing. The link is from 2017 so I was hoping that things might have changed between then and now. If no one says otherwise (in a few days) I'll accept your answer, thanks !!

Answer (score 5):

A module type script will execute immediately once parsed if it has the `async` keyword, for example:

```html
<script type="module" async src="/static/.../component.min.js">
```

See [This nice graph](https://gist.github.com/jakub-g/385ee6b41085303a53ad92c7c8afd7a6#visual-representation) for a visual representation of what is happening: